# Botão de retornar ao topo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Criei um script básico para exibir/ocultar um botão de retornar ao topo da página:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Add smooth scrolling to all links
        $("a").on('click', function(event) {
            // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                // Store hash
                var hash = this.hash;
                // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function(){
                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            } // End if
        });
        //Nav BG and TopBTN function
        (function scrollFn(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= 1){
                $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
                $(".up-scroll").addClass("display");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".up-scroll").addClass("active");
                },100);
            };
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1){
                    $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
                    $(".up-scroll").addClass("display");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".up-scroll").addClass("active");
                    },100);
                }else{
                    $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
                    $(".up-scroll").removeClass("active");
                };
            });
        })();
    });
```

```css
div{
   height:3000px
}
.up-scroll{
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
        color:#000;
        padding:6px;
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:20px;
        right:20px;
        z-index:50;
        text-align:center;
        opacity:0;
        display:none;
        transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .up-scroll.display{
        display:block;
    }
    .up-scroll.display.active{
        opacity:1;
    }
```

```html
<div>

</div>
<a href="#home" class="up-scroll"><span class="sr-only">Voltar ao topo</span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

No caso, neste snippet o botão não funcionará, ao clicar, porém, meu problema está em fazer o botão ser ocultado quando o usuário retorna para a posição 0 no scroll da página.

- Nenhum erro foi apontado no console

Comment: não é possível duplicata, se você ler a pergunta você vai entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está neste `setTimeout` que comentei:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1){
        $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
        $(".up-scroll").addClass("display");
//                    setTimeout(function(){
            $(".up-scroll").addClass("active");
//                    },100);
    }else{
        $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
        $(".up-scroll").removeClass("active");
    };
});
```

Ele está readicionando a classe `.active` quando o scroll atinge `0`, porque ele tem um delay de 100ms quando o scroll ainda é igual ou maior que `1`. Esse tempo de 100ms é um valor alto em relação ao tempo em que o scroll passa de `1` a `0`. Você pode resolver diminuindo o valor para 10, que é suficiente para que o temporizador não reinsira a classe no elemento.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Add smooth scrolling to all links
        $("a").on('click', function(event) {
            // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                // Store hash
                var hash = this.hash;
                // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function(){
                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            } // End if
        });
        //Nav BG and TopBTN function
        (function scrollFn(){
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= 1){
                $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
                $(".up-scroll").addClass("display");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".up-scroll").addClass("active");
                },100);
            };
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1){
                    $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
                    $(".up-scroll").addClass("display");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".up-scroll").addClass("active");
                    },10);
                }else{
                    $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
                    $(".up-scroll").removeClass("active");
                };
            });
        })();
    });
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}
div{
   height:3000px
}
.up-scroll{
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
        color:#000;
        padding:6px;
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:20px;
        right:20px;
        z-index:50;
        text-align:center;
        opacity:0;
        display:none;
        transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .up-scroll.display{
        display:block;
    }
    .up-scroll.display.active{
        opacity:1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
home
</div>
<a href="#home" class="up-scroll"><span class="sr-only">Voltar ao topo</span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
```

### Usando fadeIn, fadeOut

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     // Add smooth scrolling to all links
     $("a").on('click', function(event) {
         // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
         if (this.hash !== "") {
             // Prevent default anchor click behavior
             event.preventDefault();
             // Store hash
             var hash = this.hash;
             // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
             // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
             $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
             }, 800, function(){
                 // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                 window.location.hash = hash;
             });
         } // End if
     });
     //Nav BG and TopBTN function
     (function scrollFn(){
         if($(document).scrollTop() >= 1){
             $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
             $(".up-scroll").fadeIn("slow");
         };
         $(document).scroll(function(){
             if($(this).scrollTop() >= 1){
                 $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,.6)"});
                 $(".up-scroll").fadeIn("slow");
             }else{
                 $("nav").css({"background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
                 $(".up-scroll").fadeOut("slow");
             };
         });
     })();
 });
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}
div{
   height:3000px
}
.up-scroll{
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
        color:#000;
        padding:6px;
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:20px;
        right:20px;
        z-index:50;
        text-align:center;
        /*opacity:0;*/
        display:none;
        /*transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;*/
    }
/*    .up-scroll.display{
        display:block;
    }
    .up-scroll.display.active{
        opacity:1;
    }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
home
</div>
<a href="#home" class="up-scroll"><span class="sr-only">Voltar ao topo</span><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
```

Comment: Nada como alguém que entende de JS, até removi minha humilde resposta haha

Comment: Há um problema, por isso havia colocado o setTimeout, na primeira vez que o usuário descer o scroll, ele não exibe a transição de opacidade

Comment: o problema da opacidade, conforme havia informado

Comment: @MuriloGambôa No exemplo que postei a opacidade está funcionando normal. Adicionei uma outra forma usando `fadeIn` e `fadeOut` que acho até melhor, porque fica tudo dentro do jQuery sem chamar classes do CSS, que você pode até apagar do código.